# Request context with express, with react => webpack => ejs

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, ejs

I have a react app.

I am looking to transcompile the react JS using webpack.

In output, I want to include EJS templating syntax so that I may dynamically render with express using request context.

Upon adding EJS syntax to the react JSX, I get webpack syntax errors when building:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (102:7)
> 102 |       <% if (event) { %>
```

I am looking for the EJS syntax to be rendered by express, not webpack, as it is for rendering content directed by the http request context.

Is it possible to include this EJS syntax in the react JSX, preserve it as it gets transcompiled, and have express render the EJS (using request context)?

Comment: No, not embedded in JSX, but you can put it in its own file https://github.com/okonet/ejs-loader

Comment: @Andy Ray - am looking for the EJS syntax to be rendered by express, not webpack